# No route matches "/ciudades"

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing the application  in Spanish, so I had to modify the rules of pluralization for some tables,  in  table  cities i have this:

```
   ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
   inflect.plural /ciudad$/i, '\1ciudades'
   inflect.singular /ciudades/i, '\1ciudad'
   end
```

i have test for checked the setting pluralization:

```
"ciudad".pluralization
ciudades
```

run scaffold

```
rails generate scaffold ciudad nombre:string departamento_id:integer
```

and for last run migrate

`rake db:migrate`

but to the open url http://localhost:3000/ciudades the server view

```
Routing Error

No route matches "/ciudades"
```

rake routes

```
         ciudades GET    /ciudades(.:format)               {:controller=>"ciudades", :action=>"index"}
                  POST   /ciudades(.:format)               {:controller=>"ciudades", :action=>"create"}
       new_ciudad GET    /ciudades/new(.:format)           {:controller=>"ciudades", :action=>"new"}
      edit_ciudad GET    /ciudades/:id/edit(.:format)      {:controller=>"ciudades", :action=>"edit"}
           ciudad GET    /ciudades/:id(.:format)           {:controller=>"ciudades", :action=>"show"}
                  PUT    /ciudades/:id(.:format)           {:controller=>"ciudades", :action=>"update"}
                  DELETE /ciudades/:id(.:format)           {:controller=>"ciudades", :action=>"destroy"}
    departamentos GET    /departamentos(.:format)          {:controller=>"departamentos", :action=>"index"}
                  POST   /departamentos(.:format)          {:controller=>"departamentos", :action=>"create"}
 new_departamento GET    /departamentos/new(.:format)      {:controller=>"departamentos", :action=>"new"}
edit_departamento GET    /departamentos/:id/edit(.:format) {:controller=>"departamentos", :action=>"edit"}
     departamento GET    /departamentos/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"departamentos", :action=>"show"}
                  PUT    /departamentos/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"departamentos", :action=>"update"}
                  DELETE /departamentos/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"departamentos", :action=>"destroy"}
    tipo_terceros GET    /tipo_terceros(.:format)          {:controller=>"tipo_terceros", :action=>"index"}
                  POST   /tipo_terceros(.:format)          {:controller=>"tipo_terceros", :action=>"create"}
 new_tipo_tercero GET    /tipo_terceros/new(.:format)      {:controller=>"tipo_terceros", :action=>"new"}
edit_tipo_tercero GET    /tipo_terceros/:id/edit(.:format) {:controller=>"tipo_terceros", :action=>"edit"}
     tipo_tercero GET    /tipo_terceros/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"tipo_terceros", :action=>"show"}
                  PUT    /tipo_terceros/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"tipo_terceros", :action=>"update"}
                  DELETE /tipo_terceros/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"tipo_terceros", :action=>"destroy"}
```

Comment: Did you check your routes.db file?

Comment: my routes.rb files is:  
resources :ciudades
resources :departamentos
resources :tipo_terceros

Comment: Please show us the output of `rake routes`

Comment: i'm edit my post with output rake routes

Comment: hohoho yeah..   reboot my pc(its linux) and it worked. that should not be so strange. THANKS

Comment: No need to reboot the pc, just the server...

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your inflectors instead:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
 inflect.irregular 'ciudad', 'ciudades'
end
```